# how to open socket connection from being close in error

Tags: php, node.js

I get error in node.js when I'm sending message to server that my client uses forloop, I don't know why I will get close connection when the client use forloop. so is there a way to open back the connection again on the error event ?

```
socket.on('error',function(err){
       // I want to open the connection again here.

   });
```

this is how I send my message to server.

first i use ajax

```
 msg.forEach(function (msgid) {
       $.ajax({
           type: 'get',
            data: 'msg=' + msgid,
            url: 'tomyclient',
            success:function(data){
              //response from server data

           }

       });

});
```

tomyclient.php

```
if(isset($_GET['msg'])) {

    $sendmessage = $_GET['msg'];
    $host = "localhost";
    $port = 3030;


    $socket = socket_create(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, SOL_TCP) or die("Could not create socket\n");

    $errorcode = socket_last_error();
    $errormsg = socket_strerror($errorcode);

    socket_set_option($sock, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR, 1);

    $result = socket_connect($socket, $host, $port) or die("Couldn't connect to server: [$errorcode] $errormsg");

    socket_set_option($socket, SOL_SOCKET, SO_RCVTIMEO, array("sec" => 60, "usec" => 0));

    socket_write($socket, $message, strlen($message)) or die("Could not send data to server\n");

      $serverresponse= socket_read($socket, 1024,PHP_NORMAL_READ) or die("Could not read server response: [$errorcode] $errormsg"); 



       echo $serverresponse;



}
```

This is the error I get

```
[Error: write ECONNABORTED] code: 'ECONNABORTED', errno: 'ECONNABORTED', syscall: 'write'
[Error: read ECONNRESET] code: 'ECONNRESET', errno: 'ECONNRESET', syscall: 'read' 
[Error: read ECONNRESET] code: 'ECONNRESET', errno: 'ECONNRESET', syscall: 'read'
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: What is `forloop`?  Is that a specific library?  And what is the exact error message you get?

Answer (score 0):

A server cannot open a connection to a client.  So, if your socket has closed for some reason, the client will have to re-establish the connection to the server.

Now that you've shown your client code as a series of consecutive ajax calla, an ajax call is just an http request.  It will issue the http request, wait for the response and then close the connection.  http connections are not regularly kept open.

Comment: how to re-establish the connection of my client ?

Comment: @jemz - You are using an ajax call from the client.  See the 2nd paragraph I added to my answer.

Comment: @jemz - Is the socket error you're getting on the socket from the ajax call or from the socket that your PHP file is opening to read some data?

Comment: from the socket that the PHP file is opening to read some data,in my node.js server.